# how to load json file from geth

Tags: javascript, json, solidity, geth

maybe it is because I am not handy with js, but how can I load a .json file from geth console? I want this in order to avoid the clumpsy way of copy-paste each raw abi content for each one of the contracts `var abi_1 = [...]; var abi_2 = [...]; ...`. I know the console is javascript, so I tried with `require` (easy with nodejs), but it doesn't work. It is impossible in geth (js console) to load an `abi_1.json` and store it in a variable abi_1 in the same way I easily pickle a file in python? Thank you and hope this question makes sense to the community.

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the documentation[1], the geth console uses an implementation of ECMAScript in go called goja[2]. From what I know, classical JS (so no nodejs) does not have any IO functionnalities...

However, maybe you could use the 'loadScript' function available in the console + some bash.

For instance, let's say that your JSON file is located in `/tmp/abi.json`. All your JS operations can be stored in another file (let's say `/tmp/operations.js`).

You could use `geth attach http://localhost:8545 --exec "var abi = $(cat /tmp/abi.json); loadScript('/tmp/operations.js')"`

For example :
`/tmp/file.json` contains `{ 'test': 'Hello, world'}`

`geth attach http://localhost:8545 --exec "var a = $(cat /tmp/file.json); console.log(a.test)"`

Would print `Hello, world!`

That's not a perfect solution but it could be convenient to you.

[1] https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console

[2] https://github.com/dop251/goja

Comment: thank you for your contribution. this idea seems to be quite a good roundabout! for example, using an array with all necessary abi's `arr_abis` after `--exec` , or including such operations inside `operations.js` as well..